# Regular Expression Python School Class Names for Mock Project

Tags: python, regex

I have a project in python where I want to assign names for my classes in School downtown in the Michigan High School. The classes that I have are '1B, 2B and 3B', and when the user inputs their name and classroom name, their class will be validated to ensure it is correct in the specific format '1,2 OR 3', 'B' - so they cannot write '4B' or '2A' because those classes do not exist. 

So far, I have developed this block of code:

```
while True: # This starts the whole of the while loop. 
    class_name = str(input("Please enter your class name >>"))
    if re.match("1A" "2A" "3A", class_name):
        print("Incorrect. Please write your class name again.")
    else:
        print("Your class name has been accepted")
```

How can I validate the class_name variable so it can match the classroom names '1A, 2A or 3A?' Thanks, 
Taylor Hayward.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is backwards (and your syntax is wrong, too). You don't want to test for a set of *illegal* class names (that set is far too large) - you want to test against the set of *legal*  names and repeat if the test fails.

```
while True: # This starts the whole of the while loop. 
    class_name = input("Please enter your class name >>") # str() is unnecessary
    if class_name not in {"1B", "2B", "3B"}:
        print("Incorrect. Please write your class name again.")
    else:
        print("Your class name has been accepted")
        break  # Exit the while loop
```

A regex would also be possible:

```
    if not re.match("[123]B$", class_name):
```

Note the `$` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to ensure that the match ends after `B`, otherwise input like `2BC` would be accepted by the regex (`re.match()` only anchors the match to the start of the string, not the end).